# Efeitos em scroll parecido com crédito no final de um filme

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer com que o scroll role automaticamente todos os dados e ao terminar retorne ao inicio e começe tudo novamente.

Uso esse script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            var div = $('#teste');
            setInterval(function(){
                var pos = div.scrollTop();
                div.scrollTop(pos + 2);
            }, 200)
        });
    </script>
```

porém não consigo faze-lo voltar ao inicio. Mesmo recarregando a pagina ele não volta. O efeito deseja é semelhante aos créditos no final de um filme.

Alguém pode ajudar. Muito obrigado.

Comment: coloca um if dentro da função, ao final de tudo, que diga que, caso o scroll tenha chegado ao bottom (final), ele se torna 0. Depois posta o código aqui e marca como resposta :)

Comment: Murilo Gambôa, não consegui. Vou continuar a fazer alguns teste.